# Target.Address with Drop Down Value

Tags: excel, vba

I've noticed that I'm unable to use the worksheet_change function when the target address is a drop down (data validation - pulled from table).  Is there a way to do this successfully?

Example (does not work):

```
sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
    If Target.Address="$G$8" then
        sheet4.conditions
    End if
End sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: This should not be in a module, but your sheet object. With this being said, it also should be `Private Sub` as opposed to a public sub.

Comment: Thanks, @KDavis! I made that change, but the trigger event is still not working.

Comment: I've never heard of `.conditions` what is that even used for. My guess is that isn't a thing and needs to taken out

Comment: .conditions is a macro I made in sheet4 that I'm trying to run.

Comment: It works for me (with the exception of your `.conditions`). If the drop down is located in Sheet1, then this routine should be in sheet1's object (not sheet 4 that you are referencing). And the dropdown is for sure located in `$G$8`?

Comment: Thanks for checking that.  I'm not sure what's wrong.  I have several other cells that trigger the same Sheet4.conditions that all work, the only exception being that this is a drop down and not manual entry.  The code above is listed in Sheet1 and the sheet4.conditions has worked for all other functions.  Hm, perhaps I have conflicting code for G8? I'll have to go back and check.

Comment: Try also `Sheets("Sheet4").conditions` maybe?

Comment: Try creating a new sheet put the drop down in G8 and the code in that worksheet code.  Also what kind of drop down are talking about.

Comment: Everything worked for me when I made a sub called conditions

Comment: What worksheet is this code in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code in either in the wrong worksheet, or the dropdown is in a different sheet than where your code is. Try putting this in Sheet1 and make changes to "G8" on Sheet1 to see what happens

```
sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target as Range)
  If Target.Address="$G$8" then
    MsgBox "It works!"
  End if
End sub
```

I know that code works. If that works then try your code and if it doesn't work then I beleive your `sheet4.conditions` has issues

Comment: The code you posted didn't work for me.  I posted it in Sheet1 and made changes to G8.  Does it matter that G8 is a merged cell?  The merged cells are G8-H8.  I have conditional statements in Sheet4 that work calling it by G8.

Comment: Update: nevermind, I unmerged it just to check, and it still didn't work.

Comment: I tested it with the merged cells and it worked for me

Comment: I realized the issue.  The code I had preceding this was exiting the sub. Such a simple error, thanks for your help!